# Looking for a way to zero out the value for a particular field if criteria matches a list within a table in Access

Tags: ms-access

The query returns a list of store numbers (str_nbr) and their corresponding number of packages sold (Packs); I want to make the packages sold zero if the store number is listed within a table called Closed/Excluded Stores (ABC) that only has one column (Store)

IIf([str_nbr]=[Store].[Closed/Excluded Stores (ABC)],0,[Packs])

Comment: Is this about updating the stored `Packs` values or simply changing what the query displays?

Comment: You should write table.column and not column.table

as you mentioned in your question, the table is called Closed/Excluded Stores (ABC) and your column is called Store. So in the IIf statement, you should write [Closed/Excluded Stores (ABC)].[Store].

Secondly as HansUp mentioned, you need to provide further information so that we can understand the problem better and help provide a solution